# Magento 2 crashes every time I try to Enable or Disable any modules

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have Magento 2.3.3 and it's being hosted on MageMojo Stratus.

Every time I try to install, enable, or disable any modules, the front-end will work fine, but I get an unrecoverable error in the admin panel:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNext() on null in /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:529
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Locale/Manager.php(96): Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor-&gt;getInterfaceLocale()
#1 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Locale/Resolver.php(77): Magento\Backend\Model\Locale\Manager-&gt;getUserInterfaceLocale()
#2 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Resolver.php(83): Magento\Backend\Model\Locale\Resolver-&gt;setLocale(NULL)
#3 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Locale/Resolver.php(60): Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver-&gt;__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config), 'general/locale/...', 'store', NULL)
#4 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(116): Magento\Backend\Model\Locale\Resolver-&gt;__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config), 'general/locale/...', 'store', Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Interceptor) in <b>/srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php</b> on line <b>529</b><br />
```

I've tried the well known following steps and every possible variation I could think of:

```
magento maintenance:enable
magento cache:disable
rm -rf generated/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/composer_home/cache/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/
magento setup:upgrade
composer install
magento setup:di:compile
magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
magento indexer:reindex
magento cache:flush
magento cache:enable
magento maintenance:disable
```

Comment: The same thing with solution can be found here [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246034/after-installing-a-module-i-cant-login-to-my-back-end](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246034/after-installing-a-module-i-cant-login-to-my-back-end)

Comment: I've been to that post many times, it saved me in the early days, but even that hasn't been fixing it when it happens lately.

Comment: We've encountered issues with MageMojo in the past surrounding PHP op-cache; we've found that enabling/disabling modules on the server (and thus changing config.php) would take effect for the CLI service, but not the FPM service. 
They suggested we use https://github.com/gordalina/cachetool as part of our deployment process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was 2-fold:

1. To properly remove all generated content the command should be:

```sh
rm -rf generated/* var/di/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/* pub/static/*
```

2. On MageMojo's Mojo Stratus hosting, you need to simultaneously clear Varnish cache, Redis cache, PHP OP-Cache, and AWS CloudFront storage. There is a helper cli tool present on the server you can use:

```sh
...
php bin/magento cache:flush
/usr/share/stratus/cli cache.all.clear
```